# Check if file exists in cache before removing it with Liip Imagine Bundle ( and Symfony3 )

Tags: php, listener, symfony, liipimaginebundle

Seems very basic: I want to check if a file exists in Liip Imagine Bundle cache before removing it. An example: after a photo update all the cache has been deleted, only some of the thumbnails have been regenerated (say 175px ones but not 250px ones for example) and I want to delete the corresponding photo.
I'm using a listener to do that in Symfony, as I've seen others do. Here's how it looks:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Photo;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/**
 * Description of CachePhotoListener
 *
 * @author Norman
 */
class CachePhotoListener 
{
    protected $cacheManager;
    protected $request;

public function __construct($cacheManager, RequestStack $request_stack) 
{
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
    $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();        

    if ($entity instanceof Photo) {
        $this->cacheManager->remove($entity->userPath());
    }
}

// Case : remove photo
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $filters = array('thumb_prospect_250', 'thumb_prospect_175');

    foreach($filters as $filter){
        if ($entity instanceof Photo) {                
            $expectedCachePath = $this->cacheManager->getBrowserPath($entity->getPath(), $filter);            

            if (file_exists($expectedCachePath)) {
                $this->cacheManager->resolve($this->request, $entity->getPath(), $filter);
                $this->cacheManager->remove($entity->getPath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem : file_exists returns always "false" even when the thumbnail exists. Here's a sample of the $expectedCachePath variable :

```
'http://dev.playermanager/media/cache/thumb_prospect_250/uploads/photos/11/4d176797ca5c7dd753b23ca17b77630eeff0ba8d.jpg' (length=118)

boolean false

'http://dev.playermanager/media/cache/thumb_prospect_175/uploads/photos/11/4d176797ca5c7dd753b23ca17b77630eeff0ba8d.jpg' (length=118)

boolean false
```

What am I doing wrong ? (I also tried to check the files with "is_readable" and obtaining the same results)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem. I modified two things.
First I checked the presence of the photo in Liip cache with the isStored method. Second, there was a mistake in my cacheManager->resolve parameters, the $this->request parameter shouldn't have been there.

Which gives me the following preRemove function in the listener:

```
public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $filters = array('thumb_prospect_250', 'thumb_prospect_175');

        foreach($filters as $filter){
            if ($entity instanceof Photo) {                         
                $cacheExists = $this->cacheManager->isStored($entity->getPath(), $filter);        

                if ($cacheExists) {
                    $this->cacheManager->resolve($entity->getPath(), $filter);
                    $this->cacheManager->remove($entity->getPath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think calling `$this->cacheManager->getBrowserPath` [returns URL](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/0a7932e7ad53f38916dd346e1f5d9c298d65c6f3/Imagine/Cache/CacheManager.php#L130) while you want directory path.

What do you store in `$entity->getPath()`? Maybe you can check whether the file exists in `"%kernel.cache_dir%"` directory yourself.

Comment: $entity->getPath() returns a relative url, looking like this:

"uploads/photos/1/13cf43e720b12bdcafff8a002e046e186559cdc0.jpg" 

In the meantime I found a solution, but how exactly would you check if the file exists with "%kernel.cache_dir%" ?